# How to Use OpenSSL on Mac

Tags: openssl

I'm trying to generate an OpenSSL cert on my Mac (for Xero to WooCommerce integration) by following these instructions (copied below): http://developer.xero.com/documentation/advanced-docs/public-private-keypair/

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 1024
openssl req -new -x509 -key privatekey.pem -out publickey.cer -days 1825
openssl pkcs12 -export -out public_privatekey.pfx -inkey privatekey.pem -in publickey.cer
```

It works fine, and I get to the last step where I input and then verify my export password. But after I submit I see nothing. Where does the .pfx file get saved too? Should something else be displayed on screen? See screenshot below for where I am at.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The files should be saved in the same location (working directory) you ran these commands from.

If you run the command

```
pwd
```

it should show you the path to your working directory.